# Find invertible matrices over a field such that the set of a vector multiplied by them is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory, linear-independence

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field (it may have positive characteristic and/or not be algebraically closed) and let $\mathbb{F} = \overline{\mathbb{K}}$ be it's algebraic closure. Let $0 \neq v \in \mathbb{F}^n$.

I want to know if it's possible to find $P_1, \ldots, P_{n-1} \in GL_n(\mathbb{K})$ such that the set $\{ v, P_1 v, \ldots P_{n-1} v\}$ is linearly independent. In case it is I'd also like to find a way to construct said matrices.

The only semi-close attempt I've encountered only works if $char(\mathbb{K}) \neq 2$ where you find some of the vectors by multiplying by 2 the entries of $v$ that aren't 0 and do some permutations for those that are. I don't know how to start the general case or even the characteristic 2 case.

Comment: Is the choice of $P_j$ meant to be $v$-independent?

Comment: To reiterate: Is this for a single $v$ or for all $v$? For a single $v$, as the question is phrased, complete to a basis for $\Bbb F^n$.

Comment: The matrices can depend on v, that's fine. v is fixed but it can be any vector. Given v I want to find the matrices. It's not as simple as completing to a basis because the matrices coefficients must be in K.

Comment: I don’t understand. $\Bbb K$ is a field.

Comment: Here is a naive idea: if $v$ has no zero entries, we can simply extend $v$ to $v_ie_i$ for $i<n$ using the obvious projection matrices. The reason it works in this case is that the projections are in some sense dual to a $\mathbb{K}$-basis. I'm less sure about what truly "causes the problem" when entries are zero (notably: if only one zero, we could skip the projection that kills $v$ entirely, but this is still no good), but it suggests to me that projections might help avoid "whoops need $\mathbb{F}$ entries" issue that blocks the simple extend-$v$-to-basis argument.

Comment: It's easy to see that the set of $P_1,\dots,P_{n-1}$ that work is Zariski-open in $GL_n(\mathbb{F})$.  That's enough to conclude that it has an element in $GL_n(\mathbb{K})$ as long as $\mathbb{K}$ is infinite, at least.

Comment: @EricNathanStucky I guess that the projection matrices can fail to be invertible, that is to belong to $GL_n(\mathbb K)$.

Comment: Oh yes, what a silly oversight. I was wondering why other-Eric's answer looked like that, but it's essentially just an adjustment to keep things invertible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us assume without loss of generality that the $0$th entry of $v$ is nonzero.  Now let $P_i$ be the matrix given by $P_i(e_0)=e_0+e_i$ and $P_i(e_j)=e_j$ for $j\neq 0$, where $e_i$ is the $i$th standard basis vector.  Note that $P_iv=v+ae_i$, where $a$ is the $0$th entry of $v$.  It follows that $v,P_1v,\dots,P_{n-1}v$ are linearly independent, since they have the same span as $v,ae_1,\dots,ae_{n-1}$ and $a\neq 0$.

Comment: I take that the entries of vectors to be indexed starting from $0$ here for convenience of notation to match the indexing $P_1,\dots,P_{n-1}$ you use in the question (note that at the end, you need to know that specifically the $0$th entry of $v$ is nonzero for it to be linearly independent from $ae_1,\dots,ae_{n-1}$).

Comment: In that case it should be $j \geq 1$ instead of >